Building a Tic-Tac-Toe game but player two's turn gets skipped if he does a wrong turn in a row that is filled out, how do I fix this?
Firstly, I am still new to coding so please don't berate me for not doing some stuff right. Everything in the code is what I have learned so far from my classes.
So I built a Tic-Tac-Toe game and as the title says, player two's turn gets skipped if an entire row is filled out on the board.
Main Part of Code:
print("This is Tic-Tac-Toe, play this with a friend")
TicTacToe = [["-", "-", "-"], 
             ["-", "-", "-"], 
             ["-", "-", "-"]]

for row in TicTacToe:
    print(row[0],row[1],row[2])

while True:
    Player = input("Which row do you want to go; T = top, M = middle, or B = bottom?\n")

    if Player not in ["top", "Top", "T", "t", "middle", "Middle", "M", "m", "bottom", "Bottom", "B", "b"]:
        print("Wrong input, I'm afraid you are going to have to actually write what you were told to.")
        continue
    
    # These are the moves of the player, starting with Player One.

    if Player == "top" or Player == "Top" or Player == "T" or Player == "t":
        while True:
            Movement = input("Where do you want to go, L = left, M = middle or R = right?\n")
        # Checks if the movement after the player chose their option is in check
            if Movement not in ["left", "Left", "L", "l", "Middle", "middle", "M", "m", "right", "Right", "R", "r"]:
                print("That is not one of the options you are allowed to write, please write the options listed.")
                continue

            if Movement == "left" or Movement == "Left" or Movement == "L" or Movement == "l":
                if TicTacToe[0][0] == "-":
                    TicTacToe[0][0] = "X"
                    break
                else:
                    print("A move has already been placed there!")

    # Now it is the beginning of Player Two's turn

    while True: 
        Player2 = input("Now it's your turn Player Two; T = top, M = middle, or B = bottom?\n")
        
        # This is what happens if Player Two does not input the options originally listed

        if Player2 not in ["top", "Top", "T", "t", "middle", "Middle", "M", "m", "bottom", "Bottom", "B", "b"]:
            print("Wrong input, I'm afraid you are going to have to actually write what you were told to.")
            continue
        
        # Moves of Player Two

        if Player2 == "top" or Player2 == "Top" or Player2 == "T" or Player2 == "t":
            while True:
                Movement = input("Where do you want to go, L = left, M = middle or R = right?\n")
            # Checks if the movement after the player chose their option is in check
                if Movement not in ["left", "Left", "L", "l", "Middle", "middle", "M", "m", "right", "Right", "R", "r"]:
                    print("That is not one of the options you are allowed to write, please write the options listed.")
                    continue
                
                if Movement == "left" or Movement == "Left" or Movement == "L" or Movement == "l":
                    if TicTacToe[0][0] == "-":
                        TicTacToe[0][0] = "O"
                        break
                    else:
                        print("A move has already been placed there!")
                        break

So in this code block for Player two as well as the other similar ones to it, I tried changing the break under the else tag to a continue statement instead, thinking it would loop to the original question "Now it's your turn Player Two; T = top, M = middle, or B = bottom?".
Code Block:
                if Movement == "left" or Movement == "Left" or Movement == "L" or Movement == "l":
                if TicTacToe[0][0] == "-":
                    TicTacToe[0][0] = "O"
                    break
                else:
                    print("A move has already been placed there!")
                    break

Altered Code Block:
                if Movement == "left" or Movement == "Left" or Movement == "L" or Movement == "l":
                if TicTacToe[0][0] == "-":
                    TicTacToe[0][0] = "O"
                    break
                else:
                    print("A move has already been placed there!")
                    continue

Instead it loops back to the "Movement" variable which makes player two soft locked since the row is completely filled out.
If anyone knows how to fix this, please also explain why my method wasn't working and how the new method works as well.

[ask] and [mre].

break and continue only work with the immediate containing loop.

Julien, I have condensed the main part of the code to the important parts, which I apologize for not doing (I am new to stackoverflow). But John, do you know what I should do instead? Removing the "while True" above Movement makes the code stop working.

You need to adjust the logic in your code. Instead of using continue after printing "A move has already been placed there!" for Player Two, you can simply break out of the current iteration of the loop and allow Player Two to make another move.
Consider the following(keep in mind that I don't use python and there might be a problem in my code as well):
if Movement == "left" or Movement == "Left" or Movement == "L" or Movement == "l":
    if TicTacToe[0][0] == "-":
        TicTacToe[0][0] = "O"
        break
    else:
        print("A move has already been placed there!")
        break  # Break out of the current iteration to allow Player Two to make another move

The reason why using continue didn't work as expected is that continue would have skipped the remaining code in the inner loop and continued with the next iteration of that loop. Since there are no more iterations in the inner loop, it wouldn't have had the desired effect.
By using break after printing the message, you exit the inner loop, allowing Player Two to be prompted again for their move. This way, the flow of control returns to the outer loop where Player Two can make another move.

Suggested: if Movement.lower() in {'l', 'left'}:

This method would trap Player 2 in an infinite loop though. For the first ever time, yes, it would bring them back to the original question. But any times after that and he gets trapped in the loop.
